# Refactoring a multi-thread asynchronous application to prevent too many threads

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, refactoring

I'm trying to refactoring a multi-thread asynchronous application. I have a class the every time that the application launch particular event(they are generate from external devices) it launch a new thread and it register the event. After that in another class I launch a new thread that process the event and then close the two thread.
I want refactor this because if are raised 100 different events I' ll have 100 different thread(and the application will run in embedded pc like raspberry pi or marsboard).
So I have found two ways to try to solve the problem:

- Use thread pool but it has a limit so I' ll lost event thar are raised after the pool thread as reach the limit
- Use a queue: I' ll transform the application in a synchronous and single thread but at most I' ll have only one thread running.

There are other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: Using a queue doesn't mean it becomes suddenly single threaded. You can have multiple threads, but if there are peaks of events, they'll get queued.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the two solutions.

Use a threadpool and if there are no free threads, then start to queue up requests.

That is the way application servers solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using unlimited number of threads is a terrible idea indeed,
You can use `ThreadPoolExecutor` and a `BlockingQueue` instead. `ThreadPoolExecutor` has a constructor that takes a `BlockingQueue`.

Since you mentioned refactoring, try to remove mutability from the code that is gonna be used by threads.
Try to make all your types  madly immutable, if this is not possible hide mutability. This will give thread safety for free